# Нужно создать функцию которая бы считала колличество нужных мне слов/букв в строке , моя не работает

Tags: javascript

```
function _one (string, a_char) {
let count = (string.match(/a_char/g) || []).length;
console.log(count)
}
_one(ccctttc, c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function _one (string, a_char) {
  let count = string.split(a_char).length - 1;
  console.log(count);
}
_one( 'ccctttc', 'c' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Выше есть один ответ, но вот исправленный ваш:

```js
function _one (string, a_char) {
    let count = (string.match(new RegExp(a_char, 'g')) || []).length;
    console.log(count)
}
_one("ccctttc", "c")
```